# Meraki and Syslog-NG OSE

Tags: cisco, monitoring, logging, syslog, meraki

I've been struggling epically to export legible logs from my Meraki devices to a server running Syslog-NG OSE 3.30. No matter what source driver I use on the server, I see errors like this (identifying details changed):

```
May 28 15:56:23  syslog-ng[32734]: Error processing log message: <134>1>@< 1622231783.857281611 HOSTNAME2 flows allow src=10.1.1.2 dst=10.2.1.2 mac=BLAH protocol=icmp type=0
```

It seems apparent that Meraki doesn't send messages that conform to RFC3164 or RFC5424. Is that true? Why on earth not? And if so, does that mean I have to parse them specially on my Syslog-NG server with an XML file in patterndb? Can anyone point to an example of one that I can look at?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers and applications are off-topic here. Did you look at the Cisco Meraki instructions for configuring a syslog server for the logs from a Meraki device? You could ask about configuring your server on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the Cisco Meraki instructions are not helpful. Where would a question about the syslog implementation on Meraki devices be appropriate? Because it's the lack of RFC compliance in the Meraki syslog client implementation that appears to be the root cause of this problem. Surely admins configure Meraki devices to export to syslog? (I'm in a business environment.)

Comment: How do you know it is not compliant with the RFC? The log entries appear to be the same as other Cisco devices. The documentation I saw gives specific details on how to configure your log server. In any case, if you have a gripe about how Cisco does its log messages, you need to take that up with Cisco, as we cannot do anything about that here.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I've discovered that Meraki sends syslog messages with UNIX time format rather than in ISO 8601 format. That's not compliant with RFC 5424. I'm letting you know in case you think that information is of general interest to network engineers.